# Visual Force render text based on conditional?

Tags: visualforce, conditional

I want to make an output text render specific text based on a condition, for example, a variable is a certain value.

Is there a way to do an if statement in VF?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is.

`IF()` is one of the functions found on the [documentation page for Visualforce functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm).

It takes 3 parameters:

- some expression that returns a boolean value (`Name == 'Bob'`, `isActive` (no need for testing if a boolean variable is true/false, just use it directly), `1 + 1 > 1`, etc...)
- A value or expression to evaluate if the boolean test from the first parameter ends up being *true*
- A value or expression to evaluate if the boolean test from the first parameter ends up being *false*

Like any other Visualforce thing that isn't a tag, you'll need to use the *merge expression syntax*. Begin your statement with `{!`, and end it with `}`. E.g. `{! IF(User.isActive, "active", IF(User.Manager.isActive, "active", "inactive"))}`

If you don't want to use the `IF()` function, you could also likely accomplish this in your controller or controller extension.

```java
public class MyControllerExtension{
    ApexPages.StandardController stdCon;
    // If you don't add {get;set} to the end of a class variable, then it's just
    //   a class variable.
    public String conditionalValue;
    // This is a class "property", and we don't need to explicitly write a setter
    //   or getter.
    // You can still explicitly specify the code to execute when set or get is called
    //   but that's out of the scope of this question
    public String otherValue {get;set}

    public MyControllerExtension(ApexPages.StandardController con){
        this.stdCon = con;
    }

    // Methods that start with "get" (like getMethodName) can be used most places in Visualforce
    //   with {!methodName}
    public String getConditionalValue(){
        // If we've already determined the conditional value, and we haven't
        //   changed any of the things that determine this value, then there isn't
        //   much point in doing the calculation again.
        // Just return the existing value
        if(!String.isBlank(this.conditionalValue)){
            return this.conditionalValue;
        }

        // some logic to determine what conditionalValue should be

        this.conditionalValue = someValue;
        return this.conditionalValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<apex:outputText rendered="{!Name == 'Bob'}>
<!-- Options which you want to display -->
</apex:outputText>
```

**Name** is the apex class variable where we are populating Name value based on condition.

Comment: Are you able to do it for a string == value, not just bool? For example {!if(Name=='bob', true, false)}

Comment: yes we can do it for the string as well. lets say isAdmin is type of String and have value 'bob', then you can use {!if(Name=='bob', true, false)} in rendered attribute.

Comment: You don't need the elaborate if... Just `rendered="{!isAdmin}"` or `rendered="{!name == 'Bob'}` will do.